# Defining a route with unknown number of path in the middle

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a route named "articles", in the end of the route I get an id, but in the middle I can have one path, two paths, more or even no extra paths at all.

For example:

article/111

article/publication/222

article/publication/book/555

Is there a way to define such route without knowing the exact number of paths in the middle between the "articles" and the id?
I just need in the component to extract the id, the rest of the path does not interest me.

something like this-

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  
    { path: 'articles(/:param)*/:id',
        component: ArticlesComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: I did not find anything similar but Angular's official documentation mentions wild card route i.e. /** . Give it a try. I have not tested it though.

Comment: I use wild card route in my app-roting.module but here I want to catch specific route that starts with "articles" and ends with "id"

Comment: article/111
article/publication/222
article/publication/book/555
Do the above routes redirect to the same component? If so give this link a try https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3400-wildcard-routes-can-be-scoped-to-route-sub-trees-in-angular-5-1-3.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but a hack.

If `/article/anything/anything/:id` and `/article/:id` routes to same component then
you can have a seperate routing module for `ArticleComponent` like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ArticleComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ArticleComponent
  }
];
```

Since we have used the wild card route it will accept all possible routes.

and if u want to get the last path i.e. **id** which you can get from ActivatedRoute Object like below:

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
      const paths = this.route.url.value
      const id = paths[paths.length-1].path
      console.log(id);
    }
```

Comment: thanks! but the id is mandatory for the route, so path: '' will accept only 'articles'

Comment: Do you know why I get this error "- error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<UrlSegment[]>'." I can see that I can access the "value" property.

Comment: Need to do-         this.route.url.subscribe(paths => {
            const id = paths[paths.length-1].path
             console.log(id);
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can define the "middle route params" as one parameter which is a comma separated string, then split the string when parsing that URL parameter.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  
    { 
        path: 'articles/:param/:id',
        component: ArticlesComponent
    }
];
```

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
 /// do something with params.get('id')
 /// do something with params.get('param')?.split(',')
})
```

Comment: Does not work with 2 middles params.. only for one.

Comment: It won't work if you are routing like this: `this.router.navigate(['articles', 'foo', 'bar', 'id'])` but if you route like this `this.router.navigate(['articles', 'foo, bar, as, many, items, as, you, want', 'id'])`, it will.